# How to make a order-n callable function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, lambda, functional-programming, assert

You have the following code:

```
def f(val):
    return lambda x: x + val

assert f(5)(6) == 11
```

This works, but how can you make this n-order?

```
assert f(5)(6)(7)...(n) == sum of values
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: So you're sure you don't want to just pass in a list parameter and add up the values? You need it to be n function calls?

Comment: yeah, I know it's a weird problem to solve like this but the answer needs to be as an n function calls.

Comment: The difference between `f(5)(6)` returning a value and it returning a callable cannot be made by the function itself because you don't provide `n` to the first invocation. So it has to be made by the caller somehow, perhaps using a descriptor. It might help if you could elaborate on the usage and requirements.

Comment: Would it be acceptable for there to be a last call, with no value at the end of the chain? E.g. `f(1)(2)(3)()`? That's easy to do with a default argument and a conditional.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish for specifically summation of integers, inheriting from int will allow you to extend it. I see it as a big no-no, but here it is for completion's sake:

```
class A(int):
  def __call__(self, val):
   return A(self+val)
 
>>> A()
0
>>> A(5)
5
>>> A(5)(6)
11
```

Generally you can add an arbitrary function, and you can do it as a separate function (without inheriting) but it will require some special stopping value or function call to differentiate and ask for the end result.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having a special call for ending the chain, here it is:

```
from functools import partial

def f(func, initializer=None):
  sentinel = object()
  def _f(val=sentinel, oldval=initializer):
    if val is sentinel:
      return oldval
    return partial(_f, oldval=func(val, oldval))
  return _f
```

Usage:

```
>>> n_sum = f(lambda x,y: x+y, 0)  # binary function, initial value
>>> n_sum(5)(6)(7)()
18
```

Answer (score -2):

To create a callable function that can be invoked n times with the desired behavior, you can use a custom callable object (a class with the **call** method). Here's how you can achieve this:

```
class NCallableFunc:
    def __init__(self, func, val):
        self.x = val
        self.f = val

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.f = self.f(x)
        return NCallableFunc(self.f)

    def NFunc(self):
        return self.f

def test(x):
    return NCallableFunc(lambda y: x + y)

# Testing
result = test(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)  # You can chain as many calls as you want
print(result.NFunc())
```

Comment: This code doesn't work

Comment: Also better avoid mutation of the instance. You create a new one anyway!